# can't use template ref on component in vue 3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, ref, vue-composition-api

I want to get the dimensions of a vue.js component from the parent (I'm working with the experimental [script setup](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/script-setup-2/active-rfcs/0000-script-setup.md)).

When I use the ref inside a component, it works as expected. I get the dimensions:

```html
// Child.vue
<template>
  <div ref="wrapper">
   // content ...
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const wrapper = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  const rect = wrapper.value.getBoundingClientRect()
  console.log(rect) // works fine!
})
</script>
```

But I want to get the dimension inside the parent component. Is this possible?

I have tried this:

```html
// Parent.vue
<template>
  <Child ref="wrapper" />
</template>
<script setup>
import Child from './Child'
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const wrapper = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  const rect = wrapper.value.getBoundingClientRect()
  console.log(rect) // failed!
})
</script>
```

the console logs this error message:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: x.value.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

---

In the documentation I can only find the way to use `template refs` [inside the child component](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs)

does this approach not work because the refs are "closed by default" as the [rfcs description says](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/script-setup-2/active-rfcs/0000-script-setup.md#closed-by-default)?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I ran into this issue today. The problem is that, when using the `<script setup>` pattern, none of the declared variables are returned. When you get a ref to the component, it's just an empty object. The way to get around this is by using `defineExpose` in the setup block.

```js
// Child.vue

<template>
  <div ref="wrapper">
   <!-- content ... -->
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineExpose, ref } from 'vue'

const wrapper = ref(null)

defineExpose({ wrapper })
</script>
```

The way you set up the template ref in the parent is fine. The fact that you were seeing `empty object { }` in the console means that it was working.

Like the other answer already said, the child ref can be accessed from the parent like this: `wrapper.value.wrapper.getBoundingClientRect()`.

The rfc has a section talking about how/why this works: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0040-script-setup.md#exposing-components-public-interface

It's also important to note that, with the `<script setup>` pattern, your ref in the parent component will not be a ComponentInstance. This means that you can't call `$el` on it like you might otherwise. It will only contain the values you put in your `defineExpose`.

Comment: Note: you don't need to import defineExpose (otherwise, great answer! +1)

Answer (score 11):

I don't this this is necessarily related to the `<script setup>` tag. Even in the standard script syntax your second example will not work as-is.

The issue is you are putting `ref` directly on the Child component:

```jsx
<template>
  <Child ref="wrapper" />
</template>
```

and a ref to a component is **NOT** the same as a ref to the *root* element of that component. It does not have a `getBoundingClientRect()` method.

In fact, ***Vue 3 no longer requires a component to have a single root element***. You can define your Child component as :

```jsx
<template>
  <div ref="wrapper1">// content ...</div>
  <div ref="wrapper2">// content ...</div>
</template>
<script >
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Child",

  setup() {
    const wrapper1 = ref(null);
    const wrapper2 = ref(null);
 
    return { wrapper1, wrapper2 };
  },
};
</script>
```

What should be the ref in your Parent component now?

Log the `wrapper.value` to your console from your Parent component. It is actually an object of all the refs in your Child component:

```js
{
  wrapper1: {...}, // the 1st HTMLDivElement
  wrapper2: {...}  // the 2nd HTMLDivElement
}
```

You can do `wrapper.value.wrapper1.getBoundingClientRect()`, that will work fine.

Comment: duplicating error in setup(){} wrapper1 wrapper -> 2 <-

Answer (score 6):

You could get access to the root element using `$el` field like below:

```js
<template>
  <Child ref="wrapper" />
</template>

<script setup>
import Child from './Child'
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const wrapper = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  const rect = wrapper.value.$el.getBoundingClientRect()
  console.log(rect) 
})
</script
```

Comment: got an other error: `Uncaught TypeError: wrapper.value.$el is undefined`

Comment: please do `console.log(wrapper.value)` and give me the output

Comment: here is the output: https://imgur.com/a/hrwry2Z inside the script its 'null', inside the onMounted its an `empty object { }`

Comment: In my case I get object with `$el`,`$data` `$options` fields

Comment: Where is the setup method?

Comment: `<script setup>` is a new sugar syntax that replaces `setup` hook and any property is exposed without using `return{}`

Answer (score 3):

Right, so here's what you need to do:

```
// Parent component
<template>
  <Child :get-ref="(el) => { wrapper = el }" />
</template>

<script setup>
import Child from './Child.vue';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const wrapper = ref();

onMounted(() => {
  const rect = wrapper.value.getBoundingClientRect()
  console.log(rect) // works fine!
});
</script>
```

and

```
// Child component
<template>
  <div :ref="(el) => { wrapper = el; getRef(el)}">
   // content ...
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps, ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
  
const props = defineProps({
  getRef: {
    type: Function,
  },
});

const wrapper = ref();

onMounted(() => {
  const rect = wrapper.value.getBoundingClientRect()
  console.log(rect) // works fine!
});
</script>
```

To learn why, we need to check Vue's documentation on `ref`:
[Vue special-attribute 'ref'](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#ref).

On dynamic binding of (template) `ref`, it says:

```
<!-- When bound dynamically, we can define ref as a callback function,
passing the element or component instance explicitly -->
<child-component :ref="(el) => child = el"></child-component>
```

Since the `prop` lets you pass data from the parent to a child, we can use the combination of the `prop` and dynamic `ref` binding to get the wanted results. First, we **pass the dynamic `ref` callback function into the child** as the `getRef` `prop`:

```
<Child :get-ref="(el) => { wrapper = el }" />
```

Then, **the child does the dynamic `ref` binding** on the element, where it **assigns the target `el` to its `wrapper` `ref` and calls the `getRef` `prop` function** in that callback function to let the parent grab the `el` as well:

```
<div :ref="(el) => {
            wrapper = el; // child registers wrapper ref
            getRef(el); // parent registers the wrapper ref
            }">
```

Note that this allows us to have the `ref` of the `wrapper` element in both the parent **AND** the child component. If you wished to have access to the `wrapper` element **only** in the parent component, you could skip the child's callback function, and just bind the `ref` to a `prop` like this:

```
// Child component
<template>
  <div :ref="getRef">
   // content ...
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  getRef: {
    type: Function,
  },
});
</script>
```

That would let only the parent have the `ref` to your template's `wrapper`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeing the `wrapper.value` as `null` then make sure the element you're trying to get the `ref` to isn't hidden under a false `v-if`. Vue will not instantiate the `ref` until the element is actually required.

I realize this answer is not for the current question, but it is a top result for "template ref null vue 3 composition api" so I suspect more like me will come here and will appreciate this diagnosis.

Comment: you are my hero, this was exactly the problem I have, the refs I have are actually under a v-if ! and all the others are NOT going in the direction here.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more compact:

```
<script setup>
const elementRef = ref(null)

const getElementRect = () => {
  return elementRef.value.getBoundingClientRect()
}

defineExpose({
  getElementRect
})

</script>
<template>
    <div ref="elementRef">
        <!-- content ... -->
    </div>
</template>
```