# How to use a template ref on a custom component in vue 3 compositon api

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, ref, vue-composition-api

When I try to get the ref of my custom components it results in:

```
Proxy {__v_skip: true}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Proxy
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

but works just fine when replacing `d-icon-button` with a `div` tag

Here is a quick example that returns the console log from above:

```js
<template>
      <d-icon-button ref="button">
        ...
      </d-icon-button>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
/* imports ... */
const button = ref(null);

onMounted(()=>{
  console.log(button.value)
})
```

And here is the `d-icon-button` component itself: [vuelize -> d-icon-button](https://github.com/DanielTerletzkiy/vuelize/blob/next/src/components/button/DButton.vue)

I think it has something to do with the wrapper I use in every component, but that's all I know so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68841834) might be related to your issue.

You have to expose refs from  components because they are "closed" by default: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose